# Sharepoint calculated field formula syntax

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-field

I have to programmatically set the formula for a calculated field in a list.
This field has to be the sum of two other fields. Can you provide me with the syntax for the formula that I have to insert in the code? I cannot find any example.
Can you provide me also with a reference for formula syntax because I have also to create another calculated field which is the concatenation of two string fields.
Thank you

Comment: have you checked my current answer?

Comment: I replied below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calculated Field Formulas** [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx):

For your task use simply:

```
=[Column1] + [Column2]
```

Create Calculated field with server code [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.aspx)

```
using (SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs["Website_Name"])
{
    SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["MyList"];
    SPFieldCollection collFields = oList.Fields;

    string strNewFieldName = collFields.Add("MyNewColumn", 
        SPFieldType.Calculated, false);
    SPFieldCalculated strNewField =       
        (SPFieldCalculated)collFields[strNewFieldName];
    strNewField.Formula = "=[Column1]<[Column2]";
    strNewField.Update();
}
```

Create Calculated field with CSOM code [reference1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml.aspx), [reference2](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/). As you see below you need to remeember about [escape special characters in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1498401).

```
string formula = "<Formula>=FirstName&amp; \" \" &amp;LastName&amp; \" (id: \" &amp;EmployeeID&amp; \" \"</Formula>"
      + "<FieldRefs>"
      + "<FieldRef Name='FirstName' />"
      + "<FieldRef Name='LastName' />"
      + "<FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' />"
      + "</FieldRefs>";

string schemaCalculatedField = "<Field ID='<GUID>' Type='Calculated' Name='FullName' StaticName='FullName' 
   DisplayName='Full Name' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>" + formula + "</Field>";
Field fullNameField = demoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaCalculatedField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Working code for your implementation (comments):

```
string formula = "<Formula>=Nome1&amp;&quot; &quot;&amp;Cognome1&amp;&quot;(id:&quot;&amp;Campo1&amp;&quot;)&quot;</Formula>" + "<FieldRefs>" + "<FieldRef Name='Nome1'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='Cognome1'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='Campo1'/>" + "</FieldRefs>";
string schemaCalculatedField = "<Field ID='1F2ABCC0-D243-40F0-A18D-E0AEF7FE3EB6' Type='Calculated' Name='FullName' StaticName='FullName' DisplayName='Full Name' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>" + formula + "</Field>"; 
Field fullNameField = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("PnP Custom List3").Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaCalculatedField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I forgot to tell that I need to create them with CSOM code. I tried the CSOM example but it did not work, what do you mean by encoding special characters in xml?

Comment: update your question with your CSOM code. I meant escape: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1498401

Comment: string formula = "<Formula>=Nome1&amp;\"\"&amp;Cognome1&amp;\"(id:\"&amp;Campo1&amp;\"\"</Formula>"
                      + "<FieldRefs>"
                      + "<FieldRef Name='Nome1'/>"
                      + "<FieldRef Name='Cognome1'/>"
                      + "<FieldRef Name='Campo1'/>"
                      + "</FieldRefs>";

Comment: string schemaCalculatedField = "<Field ID='1F2ABCC0-D243-40F0-A18D-E0AEF7FE3EB6' Type='Calculated' Name='FullName' StaticName='FullName' DisplayName = 'Full Name' ResultType = 'Text' Required = 'TRUE' ReadOnly = 'TRUE' > " + formula + " </ Field > ";
                    Field fullNameField = clientContext.Web.GetListByTitle("PnP Custom List3").Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaCalculatedField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: I tested your solution but it throws an error saying that "I cannot use DTD..."